# How can I install go-migrate on a container in Docker?

Tags: docker, go, containers, migrate

I am studying containers and Docker, and I am trying to run a container with go-migrate but I am getting this error:

```
Dockerfile:33
--------------------
  32 |
  33 | >>> RUN curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/golang-migrate/migrate/script.deb.sh | bash && \
  34 | >>>     apt-get update && \
  35 | >>>     apt-get install migrate
  36 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/golang-migrate/migrate/script.deb.sh | bash &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install migrate" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

I am using a M1 Macbook and the dockerfile is:

```
FROM golang:1.20.3

RUN curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/golang-migrate/migrate/script.deb.sh | bash && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install migrate
```

Comment: What do you think `apt-get install migrate` exactly does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also an [go install](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/blob/master/cmd/migrate/README.md#unversioned) option to install migrate. Since you are using a go image hence it would be easier to install it that way
e.g.

```
FROM FROM golang:1.20.3
RUN go install -tags 'mysql' github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate@latest
```